# Background service stops as soon as the app closed

Tags: android, service, background-service

I am creating a messaging app for that I need a service to receive message even when the app is closed or open, I have a broadcast receiver to receive SMS and I created a service class and started in my mainActivity as

```
Intent mIntent=new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
startService(mIntent);
```

and in the manifest, I added the service as

```
 <service android:name=".BackgroundService"
            android:enabled="true"/>
```

### broadcastReceiver class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
    if (intentExtras != null) {

        Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
        String smsMessageStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) 
sms[i]);

            smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
            address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();


            smsMessageStr += "SMS FROM :" + address + "\n";
            smsMessageStr += "Message :" + smsBody + "\n";
        }
            Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

### backgroundService.java

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service{

private SmsBroadcastReceiver mSmsBroadcastReceiver;
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 999;


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mSmsBroadcastReceiver=new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
    mIntentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    mIntentFilter.setPriority(999);
    registerReceiver(mSmsBroadcastReceiver,mIntentFilter);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

I HAVE TRIED foreground service also as

```
 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("TutorialsFace Music Player")
            .setTicker("TutorialsFace Music Player")
            .setContentText("My song")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,
            notification);
```

but as soon as I close my app from recent apps the service also gets stopped 
and when I restart my app its the service gets starting

how can I make my service to live long even when the app is closed. Because my app is SMS based one so without service I cant receive the messages while my app is closed,
any help will be appreciated,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the service is working in the same thread with the app you can override the method onDestroy to launch your service again with his own thread.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class));
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but its not working the service get closed as soon the app is closed

Comment: Yes, you can't keep this service alive you need re-start the service again and to do this you need to add Override onDestroy on your service class, hope this helps you!

Comment: yes i did the same ondestroy method i restarted my service but still the service get closed with app close

Comment: Oh I see you need more info on Manifest If you want you can check this project I'm working in [flyve-inventory-agent service](https://github.com/flyve-mdm/flyve-mdm-android-inventory-agent/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/org/flyve/inventory/agent/InventoryService.java) and [manifest](https://github.com/flyve-mdm/flyve-mdm-android-inventory-agent/blob/develop/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) with a simple example